# Marker dissipates on White board paint

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What causes white board markers to dissipate when writing on dry erase painted surfaces. It almost immediately start to pull together and seems as if it disappears

Comment: "Dissipate" is quite the opposite of what you seem to mean.

Comment: @FellowUsers: This is **not a duplicate** (though the poor wording makes it superficially similar). It's a phenomenon I experience quite often myself: Using markers to write on white-boards, result in smooth, continuous lines. However, if I use the same marker to write over another surface (like a plastic), there are times when I notice the lines of wet ink begin to "pull together" and shrink into shallow puddles. Zhe's answer correctly addresses this question. I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is competition between the intermolecular forces that pull the solvent together and the forces that cause the solvent to adhere to the surface. In this case, the solvent's interactions with itself are greater, causing the ink to bead. Since the amount of ink that is actually drawn out when writing is very small, the beads of ink are tiny and very hard to see.